# Is this the most ridiculous moderator response ever?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

So **go ahead** and get your down-votes ready. Because I don't care given my pure disgust at this:

> The user who goaded this return should be banned. Numerous examples of bad behavior have been given. – Neil Lunn Mar 28 at 14:10   declined - No, no it's not. They've very clearly explained how this was written to address problems they saw in your answer, and it is not plagiarized from your own.

The question in context is [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689851/reduce-the-response-of-mongodb-query/22691975#22691975).

Points are (and you probably need to see deletions for correct context):

- **Absolute plagiarism** (notice how I can actually spell) of an answer given by another user to try and claim as their own. Denied?
- **Clear** evidence that the user "claiming" their own response "completely failed" to evaluate the scope of the problem in their own initial comment.
- If you **are** a moderator it should not be **hard** to "match" that the person noted as "goading" within

So the summary is:

- There **was** an answer provided that should have been of acceptable quality to the OP. Especially noting that the *alteration* **still** does not meet the **exact** requirements of the OP. We treat these with the noted *inexperience* of the OP to simply "copy and paste" something they *expect* as an output, though the actual result is difficult and unnecessary to achieve.

I have taken **a lot** of my personal time to try and "contribute" within the scope of the site. This is **not** about personal status or gain and I have spent "considerable" time providing very "lengthy" explanations to those who "appear" to be new and possibly *inexperienced* users, and I do hope that there is **some** benefit found by those you search the "knowledge-base" in the future, as a result.

I **do not** appreciate someone "plagiarizing" an answer, "albeit" with their "specific take" on how it **should** be presented in their eyes.

I also "loathe" the **bad** behavior of users who "goad" someone into an activity that suits their own personal needs. I **persuaded** ( originally ) the user who "plagiarized" the response to "re-consider" what they have done. And I have done so with other examples of "bad behavior". But to have someone come back and say, "essentially", "Yes, they did not want to change the answer given just because you left a **lot** of comments, so there is nothing wrong with you **copying** their answer and adding what "you" think is appropriate.

I have ranted **too long**. Point it this was a **bad call** by a moderator, and a complete **fail** on reviewing a history of targeted behavior by a user.

Anyhow **down-vote away**. My point is that this should not be ignored and there should not be a lack of "re-course" since in this case I raised the flags **"three times"**.

Shock me and provide a real answer. Or even better, the action that **should** have happened after having to deal with this on multiple occasions.

Comment: How about not pre-supposing how people will react? Inviting downvotes normally results in... downvotes. In particular when going in with a combative tone.

Comment: You may have a case, but the rant isn't really necessary nor productive. Consider spending your energy on making super clear *why* the user should be banned instead.

Comment: "I think Neil Lunn's answer is mostly correct, but in my opinion it needs a few tweaks to get the expected result". He is being polite. He give proper attribution. He try to improve the overall contents. **why have him banned**? If you disagree with what he writes and think it's still not changing what you wrote, downvote, comment and move on. You don't get hurt by this.

Comment: Also, what do you think "goaded this return" means? Because it is nonsensical.

Comment: I don't see any problem with other people adding on to someone else's answer, while keeping their answer relevant to the question being asked. Rather, it is harder to get the original author to accept an edit than writing your own answer.

Comment: The **random** bolding makes this question **feel** like riding over a field of **speedbumps**.

Comment: I've made a couple of tweaks to the answer.  Does that satisfy your objections?

Comment: This isn't plagiarism. The other guy never posted a copy/paste of your answer. His code was a modification of yours. People are *actively discouraged* from editing code in other people's answers, so other than commenting, posting a modified answer of your own is really the only acceptable thing to do when you want to post an improvement (perceived or otherwise).

Comment: I concur.  It's not plagiarism.  Everything on here is CC-BY-SA, and he gave you credit for  the original answer.  So I really don't see what the problem is here.

Comment: How many times have we seen a meta question where someone is complaining about a rejected edit to answer because they thought the answer was close but could be better.  In almost every single case that I can recall, the solution suggested by the community was **provide your own answer, don't edit the existing answer**.  So this user did exactly that.  I fail to see the problem.  And now that you've been given credit and a link back to your post after the edits, it even complies with the CC-BY-SA license.

Comment: FWIW, [original revision of the flagged answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22691975/1) smells like a plagiarism: code appears to be copied, there's no attribution, and the only stuff added looks ridiculously trivial ("output")

Comment: @NeilLunn I think your anger/feelings cause you to see trolls everywhere. Relax, calm down. Coffee. Get some air. Things will look much less intimidating when you'll get back. Nobody here is trolling just trying to explain the situation as they see it, Brad doing it the best in the answer, in my opinion.

Comment: @gnat true, but he edited it 8 minutes afterwards.

Comment: @ShadowWizard given that the flagged answer was posted about an hour after original one, it looks quite slippery that it was submitted that way, don't you think? I mean, there's not even a fastest gun race to justify posting it like that

Comment: @gnat: I doubt there's anything in any way malicious going on here.  See the highlighted comment conversation below.

Comment: @RobertHarvey there was never anything malicious with the user posting . I have in fact "praised" him for his efforts. The "goading" user is clearly seen in the comments of the original question. And multiple flags (accepted) have been raised for this type of behavior.

Comment: You're "not" using quotation marks "correctly", and you "should" lay off the **bold** and *italics*. Every place you've quoted a word in your question, you should remove the quotes around that word, because you've *only* misused them - there are literally zero instances of correct quote usage in your post. [Quotation marks are not for emphasis](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/punctuation-errors-quotation-marks-for-emphasis/).

Comment: @NeilLunn: When you cast a moderator flag, you have to ask yourself the following question: *what community-aversive behavior is being demonstrated here?*

Comment: @NeilLunn: Look at the conversation highlighted in the answer below.  That conversation is exactly how things are supposed to work here.  The only mistake that Anand made is not crediting you in his original answer, but he fixed that 8 minutes later.  If goading is the only problem here, the way to fix that is to walk away from the conversation.

Comment: @NeilLunn He *didn't* just copy an answer.  He created a new answer that was based, in part, on your answer, to which he cited you appropriately.  You very specifically gave everyone in the entire world the right to do this when you posted your content on the site.  If you are not comfortable allowing people to create derived works from your contributions, so long as they cite you, then you should not post content to the site.

Comment: @NeilLunn The very first comment (to something in the first paragraph) was posted 2 minutes after you posted. Where are you getting your numbers from?

Comment: @NeilLunn: That conversation is the entire conversation under that answer; none of the comments were left out.  Alas, I see (belatedly) that you're merely here to bitch, not gain insight, so I'm outta here.

Comment: @NeilLunn You're still not using "quotes" correctly. The fact that you don't know how to write them leads me to assume that you don't know how to read them, which means you're actually misunderstanding virtually every sentence written which contains quotes. They do *not* provide emphasis! Your sentence above, where you say "mistake"? That means you don't really think they made a mistake. You're pretty much using them *backwards*.

Comment: @meagar: You just don't know how to "read" english.

Answer (score 50):

For context, you originally left [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22690710/19679). These are the comments that followed on that answer, which were removed by both parties:

[image]

Anand then left [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22691975/19679) to point out elements they believed to be wrong in yours. You flagged that as

> Plagarism. Simply copying knowledge gained from another answer and presenting it as their own.

which I declined, because this is clearly not plagiarism. They expanded on your answer, gave you proper credit, and contributed new material.

You then flagged it with the above, which I again declined.

I have no idea what "The user who goaded this return should be banned" means at all, because we can't ban people, nor would we suspend someone posting a legitimate answer.

Frankly, I think you might need to step away from the computer for a little while to calm down, because there's no malice in any of this.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, "plagiarized" is a legitimate spelling of the word: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plagiarize .

Comment: Third Reversal badge on its way. :)

Comment: And here it is :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard do these badges even mean anything on meta? Just reply to a rant :-)

Comment: So then if it was you you seem to hav a complete misunderstanding of the english language or indeed the context of the comment. The guy who said **no you cant** cannot possibly come up with the **yes you can like this** response by himself. That is pretty poor judgement and I stand by it.

Comment: Additionally. And if you are actually a moderator then **bad form** because you failed to quote that I stated (sic) "Copying an answer like this cannot be your own answer". And gee! Somehow that got through to the poster ( god knows how ) and then there were unwarranted comments from a generally offensive miscreant (look that one up). You made a mistake. Deal with it.

Comment: @JanDvorak same as reputation, but more shiny.

Comment: @Neil `Copying an answer like this cannot be your own answer` that's not true. And I don't see where you get the information from that Anand is a "offensive miscreant"? I just went through the first couple pages of his comments and saw nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Btw , isnt everything posted under the creativecommons license ? So the second person just had to attribute the content of the first guy , which he did .

Answer (score 16):

## The issue

Stack Exchange system is one of competing answers; different ways of solving the same problem, these answers are then voted on and the best floats to the top.

In this case you and Anand Jayabalan had differing opinions on how this question should be solved, this was initially discussed in the comments and finally when the two of you could not agree on the best way to answer the question, Anand Jayabalan posted a separate answer using the method Anand thought was best.

This is exactly the way things are supposed to happen, the votes will ultimately decide which is best. There is no need to flag in this case, especially as the common material between the two is correctly attributed. Given that (from the comments) you believe that Anand's answer is wrong, it cannot simultaneously be a complete plagiarism of your answer.

### The key differences that make the posts different

The differences between the posts have existed since Anand's first [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22691975/1) but are better highlighted in [later revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22691975/2187042). For example Anand uses the following code

```
{ "$match": {
    "worktypes.name": "Pompas"
}},
```

whereas Neil uses

```
{ "$match": {
    "worktypes.works.name": "work 1"
}},
```

The use of worktypes.works.name vs worktypes.name seems to have been a major discussion point and not just a cosmetic difference.

### The flag itself

> The user who goaded this return should be banned. Numerous examples of
> bad behavior have been given

I have no idea what that means, if I were a mod I would probably decline it with a message of "unclear what you're flagging". Don't make vague references to things and make mods guess. Be explicit about what you think is wrong.

Comment: [original version of flagged answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22691975/1) doesn't seem to support the idea of " differing opinions" don't you think

Comment: @gnat While odd, the long comment discussion beforehand suggest disagreement (with perhaps an accidental wrong submit) rather than plagurism

Comment: comparing times displayed at comments screen shot (`15:35`) and in the original revision (`15:19`), I would say that discussion happened _after_ the flagged answer was posted, not before

Comment: @gnat Actually even the first version has the differences, `{"$match": {"worktypes.name": "Pompas"` in Anand's from the very beginning and `{ "$match": {"worktypes.works.name"` in Neils. Which was the key part of the discussion

Comment: @Richard Tingle: IT'S SPELLED PLAGIARISM!!!

Comment: @gnat look at the screen shot again. The comments were posted between 14:48 and 14:55 with the final one at 15:21 notifying neil that he posted an own answer. The times you were looking at is only the time the comments were deleted.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Lol, I must admit I'm (somewhat) careful with spelling in the main post but the comments are a free for all

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl thanks! I did not notice that